# Let $f$ be glide reflection, prove $\frac{1}{2}(\vec x + f(\vec x)) \in g$

Tags: geometry

Let $f$ be a glide reflection with $\sigma_{\lambda,g}=\vec x + 2 (d-\vec n \bullet \vec x) \vec n+\lambda \vec{n_r}=A\vec x + 2 d\vec n + \lambda \vec{n_r}$ with $g=\lbrace \vec x:\vec n \bullet \vec x =d \rbrace$ ([Hesse normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hesse_normal_form)) and $A=\begin{pmatrix} n_2^2-n_1^2 & -2n_1n_2 \\ -2n_1n_2 & -n_2^2+n_1^2\end{pmatrix}$

Now I want to prove, that for all $\vec x \in \mathbb{R}^2: \frac{1}{2}(\vec x + f(\vec x)) \in g$ holds.

I already prooved that for a point reflection $d_{A,Z}(\vec x)=A(\vec x - \vec z)$ the equation $\frac{1}{2}(\vec x + f(\vec x)) = \vec z$ holds (because $f(\vec x)=-(\vec x-\vec z)+\vec z =2 \vec z - \vec x$ and $\frac{1}{2}(\vec x + f(\vec x))=\frac{1}{2} 2 \vec z = \vec z$).

I tried to start at the same point as my previous proof, but I didn't get very far.

Perhaps anyone can give me a hint?

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\frac12\bigl(x+f(x)\bigr)
&= \frac12\Bigl(x+\bigl(x+2(d-n\cdot x)n+\lambda n_r\bigr)\Bigr) \\
&= \frac12\bigl(2x+2(d-n\cdot x)n+\lambda n_r\bigr) \\
&= x+(d-n\cdot x)n+\frac\lambda2 n_r \\
n\cdot\left(\frac12\bigl(x+f(x)\bigr)\right)
&= n\cdot\left(x+(d-n\cdot x)n+\frac\lambda2 n_r\right) \\
&= n\cdot x + d(n\cdot n) - (n\cdot x)(n\cdot n) + \frac\lambda2(n\cdot n_r) \\
&= n\cdot x + d\,\lVert n\rVert^2 - (n\cdot x)\lVert n\rVert^2 + \frac\lambda2(n\cdot n_r) \\
&= n\cdot x + d - n\cdot x + 0 \\
&= d
\end{align*}

Comment: So I see, my idea was correct, but I got stuck at the dot product properties. Thanks a lot.